# Check if job is running on another server in the same network using Ansible

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, ansible, ansible-playbook

On a private Network, I have two servers, let's call them server01 and server02. They are in the same network.

The second server is rebound server i-e if server01 is no longer active, the second server must make sure to take over and run certain jobs, especially with Ansible.

On my server01, I have this ansible:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure to run script bash every minutes
      cron:
        name: "Launch Indicators job"
        minute: "*/1"
        job: "bash /root/indicators/indicator_job.sh && docker-compose up"
```

This ansible playbook makes sure to run a bash script and a docker image.

Now, that I would like to know is how with ansible I could check if this job is running every minute on server01, if not, run it in the same way on server02. Using Ansible is not imperative for checking the "**health**" of the job running under the ansible playbook I describe below. I just would like to make sure be able to check the status of this job, if is not running, lauchn the same on the second server. Just to be clear, I have no possibility to use another server or machine. I have to use the server01 and the server02 to make this possible.

Comment: This calls for a proper HA solution (e.g. pacemaker, corosync, whatever).

Comment: im thinking `ps aux | grep ansible | grep <keyword>` solution for my own needs, for you maybe run ssh command to other machine to check that.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dedicated [job scheduling software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software). Some of them are open source.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider a simple active/standby solutions like: keepalived. For every minute health check process status, you should use script (health check condition and action) + crontab (schedule job run every minutes).